# jquery next previous with non-preload image

Tags: jquery, image, slider, jquery-selectors, gallery

I'm creating a very simple image gallery that only load the first image of the gallery. User need to click on the thumbnail to view the image. This is because I'm using a large image for the gallery so that it don't have to load every image. And right now I'm having a problem creating a next and previous button.

This is the where the image load

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="img-box">
<img id="img-preview" src="#" >
</div>
</div>
```

This is the pagination

```
<div class="paginate">  
<a href="#" class="prev"></a>
<a href="#" class="next"></a>
</div>
```

This is where the thumbnail belong

```
<ul id="related-category"> 
<li class="photo"><a href="#" ></a></li>
<li class="photo"><a href="#" ></a></li>
<li class="photo"><a href="#" ></a></li>
<li class="photo"><a href="#" ></a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
jqu(document).ready(function(){

jqu("#related-category li a").click(function(){

    var largePath = jqu(this).attr("href");    
    jqu("#img-preview").attr({ src: largePath });
    return false;
    
});

    jqu("a.next").click(function(){
    jqu(" li.photo").next("a");
});
    jqu("a.prev").click(function(){
    jqu("li.photo").prev("a");
});
});
```

I've been looking for a solution, but most of the slider images are preload as the slider load while mine doesn't.

Comment: jQuery language == JavaScript language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.next()` and `.prev()` methods don't cause a click to happen, they create a jQuery object that contains the next or previous element at the same level in the DOM as the current one. So `jqu("li.photo").next("a")` won't find anything because there is no anchor at the same level as the li elements, and in any case `"li.photo"` selects *all* of the li elements.

I'd suggest you set a flag (use a class) on the clicked li to remember which one it is, and then you can use `.next()` and `.prev()` from *that* element:

```
jqu("#related-category li a").click(function(){
    jqu("#related-category li").removeClass("selected");
    jqu(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    var largePath = jqu(this).attr("href");    
    jqu("#img-preview").attr({ src: largePath });
    return false;    
});

jqu("a.next").click(function(){
    jqu("li.selected").next().find("a").click();
});
jqu("a.prev").click(function(){
    jqu("li.selected").prev().find("a").click();
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iruyap/1/edit

(Note: you may like to add some code to the prev and next handlers to do something if there is no previous or next item.)